# Error installing MaaS on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE

Tags: dpkg, maas

Got this error when installing MaaS. Try install mass-cluster-controller individually and got same error. Why?

```
-- dpkg: error processing package maas-cluster-controller (--configure):

MaaS Error Output
------------
stack@ubuntu1404:~$ sudo apt-get install maas-cluster-controller
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
maas-cluster-controller is already the newest version.
maas-cluster-controller set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up maas-cluster-controller (1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-region-admin", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-region-admin", line 64, in main
    run()
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-region-admin", line 57, in run
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/share/maas/maas/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    object.__setattr__(django.conf.settings, "__class__", LazySettings)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
dpkg: error processing package maas-cluster-controller (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up maas-region-controller-min (1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-region-admin", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-region-admin", line 64, in main
    run()
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-region-admin", line 57, in run
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/share/maas/maas/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    object.__setattr__(django.conf.settings, "__class__", LazySettings)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
dpkg: error processing package maas-region-controller-min (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas-dns:
 maas-dns depends on maas-region-controller-min (= 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1); however:
  Package maas-region-controller-min is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package maas-dns (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas-region-controller:
 maas-region-controller depends on maas-dns (= 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1); however:
  Package maas-dns is not configured yet.
 maas-region-controller depends on maas-region-controller-min (= 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1); however:
  Package maas-region-controller-min is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package maas-region-controller (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas:
 maas depends on maas-cluster-controller (= 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1); however:
  Package maas-cluster-controller is not configured yet.
 maas No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                    depends on maas-region-controller (= 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1); however:
  Package maas-region-controller is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package maas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 maas-cluster-controller
 maas-region-controller-min
 maas-dns
 maas-region-controller
 maas
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
stack@ubuntu1404:~$ dpkg -l | grep maas-region-controller
iU  maas-region-controller                                1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1                      all          MAAS server complete region controller
iF  maas-region-controller-min                            1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1                      all          MAAS Server minimum region controller
```

Comment: Have you tried removing it and installing it again? e.g. `sudo apt-get purge maas-cluster-controller`. **This will remove all configuration.** `sudo apt-get install maas-cluster-controller`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, with a stand alone maas-region-controller and the solution was install maas-cli, can you try that?

$ sudo apt install maas-cli